# i18n - update labels

Tags: javascript, hybrid-mobile-app, i18next

I am preparing the framework for a multilanguage hybrid app. I would like to use i18n as multilanguage library. The problem I am facing is really simple but I couldn't find proper documentation:

Let's say i set the language to "de", from this point on everytime I call i18n.t("some_key"), the "de" translation is returned, but, for every label which are already rendered, the text doesn't change.

Is there a way to refresh all text labels rendered by i18n, also the one already in the page? Or the only alternative is to save the new selection somewhere and reload everything so that the init() command will take into account the saved info? (e.g. cookie?)

Answer (score 1):

That depends on the framework you are using. If you decide to use JQUERY it is simple. Check this other post that resolves this issue with JQUERY:

[How to dynamically change language using jquery-i18n-properties and JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15637059/1959948)

Angular also implements i18n and allows to switch languages at runtime:

Doing something like:

```
$translate.use('es');
```

http://www.ng-newsletter.com/posts/angular-translate.html

Comment: thanks, I see in the example that the part to be translate is .empty() and then .append(...) so basically it's rerendered again. The approach then would be store all the labels inside some span with a particular class, then, when setLng is called, all the spans are visited and the values updated, there is no way to do this "out of the box" right?